# Spring Neo4j - autowire repository returns null

Tags: java, spring, interface, neo4j, annotations

I'm fairly new to Spring (the Neo4j side), and I am having trouble `@AutoWire`-ing my repository.
this is my repo:

```
package org.jarivm.relationGraph.objects.repositories;
public interface EmployeeRepository extends GraphRepository<Employee> {
    @Query("MATCH a=(:Employee)-[:WORKED_ON]->(p:Project) WHERE id(p)={0} RETURN a")
    Iterable<Employee> getTeamMates(Project client);
}
```

my test class:

```
 package org.jarivm.relationGraph;

import org.apache.commons.collections4.set.ListOrderedSet;
import org.jarivm.relationGraph.objects.domains.Employee;
import org.jarivm.relationGraph.objects.domains.Project;
import org.jarivm.relationGraph.objects.repositories.EmployeeRepository;
import org.jarivm.relationGraph.utilities.NodeProperties;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.Iterator;


/**
 * @author Jari Van Melckebeke
 * @since 02.09.16
 */
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)
public class Tests extends Application {
    @Autowired
    private Facade facade;
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        facade = new Facade();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        facade.tearDown();
    }

/*
    @Test
    public void persistedEmployeeShouldBeRetrievableFromGraphDB() {
        Employee employee = new Employee("john", "adams");
        //System.out.println(session.getTransaction().status());
        if (!facade.findEmployeeByProperty("name", employee.getName()).iterator().hasNext()) {
            facade.commit(employee);

            Employee foundHim = facade.findEmployeeByProperty("name", employee.getName()).iterator().next();
            assert foundHim.getId().equals(employee.getId());
            assert foundHim.getName().equals(employee.getName());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void persistedChainShouldBeRetrievableFromGraphDB() {
        Employee employee = new Employee("john", "myles");
        Client client = new Client();
        Sector sector = new Sector();
        Project project = new Project();
        client.setName("Real Dolmen");
        project.setClient(client);
        project.setCost(100.0);
        project.setName("project highrise");
        Set<Employee> set = new ListOrderedSet<Employee>();
        set.add(employee);
        project.setTeam(set);
        sector.setName("game");
        client.setSector(sector);
        facade.commit(sector);
        facade.commit(employee);
        facade.commit(client);
        facade.commit(project);

        Client foundHim = facade.findClientByProperty("name", client.getName()).iterator().next();
        assert foundHim.getId().equals(client.getId());
        assert foundHim.getName().equals(client.getName());
    }


    @Test
    public void projectShouldBeInsertableAlone() {
        Project project = new Project();
        project.setName("random");
        project.setLanguage("Java");
        facade.commit(project);

        Project foundHim = facade.findProjectByProperty("name", project.getName()).iterator().next();
        assert foundHim.getId().equals(project.getId());
    }

    @Test
    public void clientShouldBeInsertableAlone() {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.setName("Colruyt");

        facade.commit(client);

        Client foundHim = facade.findClientByProperty("name", client.getName()).iterator().next();
        assert foundHim.getId().equals(client.getId());
    }*/

    @Test
    public void createdNodesShoudBeEditable() {
        Iterator<Employee> employees = facade.findEmployeeByProperty("name", "john").iterator();
        Project project = facade.findProjectByProperty("name", "random").iterator().next();
        while (employees.hasNext()) {
            Employee e = employees.next();
            if (project.getTeam() == null)
                project.setTeam(new ListOrderedSet<Employee>());
            project.getTeam().add(e);
        }
        facade.commit(project);
    }


    package org.jarivm.relationGraph;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Test
    public void teamMatesShouldBeViewable() {
        Project p = facade.findProjectByProperty("name", "Matsoft").iterator().next();
        System.out.println(p);
        System.out.println(employeeRepository);
        Iterable<Employee> e = employeeRepository.getTeamMates(p);
        System.out.println(e.iterator());
    }
}
```

and my Application.java class:

```
package org.jarivm.relationGraph;

import org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

/**
 * @author Jari Van Melckebeke
 * @since 23.09.16
 */
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.jarivm.relationGraph"})
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "org.jarivm.relationGraph.objects.repositories.EmployeeRepository")
public class Application extends Neo4jConfiguration {

public static final String URL = System.getenv("NEO4J_URL") != null ? System.getenv("NEO4J_URL") : "http://localhost:7474";

@Bean
public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration getConfiguration() {
    org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration config = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();
    config
            .driverConfiguration()
            .setDriverClassName("org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.http.driver.HttpDriver")
            .setURI(URL)
    .setCredentials("neo4j", "mypassword");
    return config;
}

@Override
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return new SessionFactory(getConfiguration(), "org.jarivm.relationGraph.objects.domains");
}
}
```

The @autowire did never work with this program so I do not know what the problem is...
thank's in advance,
Jari Van Melckebeke

Comment: Can you add the package name for your repo?

Comment: Can you post your full test class signature - you normally need annotations on the test class itself / extend from a Spring base text class to enable dependency injection in unit tests

Comment: did it, good enough? or do I have to post something else? my project is by the way on github (https://github.com/N00bface/Real-Dolmen-Stage-Opdrachten/tree/master/src/main/java/org/jarivm/relationGraph)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your Tests class should not extend Application, but instead be annotated with RunsWith - something like (untested):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=org.jarivm.relationGraph.Application.class, loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class
public class Tests {
```

for more information, see the section titled *Integration Testing with @Configuration Classes*:

- https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles